# Javascript settimeout on recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, timeout

```
function theFunction(a){
    var newNum = a+1;
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var currURL = urlArray[a];
    iframe.src = currURL;
    iframe.frameBorder = "0";
    iframe.height = "0";
    iframe.width = "0";

iframe.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = a;
};
    var arrayLength = someArray.length;

    if(a != arrayLength){
     theFunction(newNum);
     }
}
```

This is my basic function that is recursive through an array. Anyways, sometimes as it goes through (during the //do nothing part). It will get stuck, and I want it to timeout after say 2 seconds AND move onto the next one.  Is this possible to do, or will I just have to completely stop the function?

EDIT: Set timeout might not be what I am looking for, but some way to just stop the function and move to the next one.

EDIT 2: Added more to the code

Comment: What exactly do you want to have happen? Have your function "pause" for 2 seconds before it does the next recursive call?

Comment: ideally I would like for it to just run normally, but if it notices the function takes more than 2 seconds to run, it skips to the next iteration.

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible in Javascript, though I may be wrong.

Comment: Is there possibly another reason for it getting "stuck" that you can debug for? I can't imagine a function such as this getting stuck unless it gets put into an infinite loop. I feel there must be a workaround without using setTimeOut(). Please inform us of exactly what else is going on in this code, such as array values and so forth.

Comment: Yea, during the commented section it is loading external pages. Usually (95% of the time) it loads in fractions of a second and works perfectly, but sometimes it finds a page that is slow/large file/missing/whatever and may take longer to load.  For those pages I want it to just skip and move on.

Comment: Ok great, that is definitely where you want to solve the problem. If you could update the code with the external page loading section I bet we could help you further.

Comment: @andbeyond I updated it.  It is simply just loading an invisible iframe of the URLs. (Basically I needed to load the URLs to run a script on each of the pages and they are php/js/asp...).

Comment: This really should even be waiting for the iframe to finish loading... Something else seems to be the culprit could you do something as simple as wrap it in a try catch?

Comment: @CoryGwin it does wait for the iFrame to stop loading, but the problem is sometimes is takes a long time to load it, and I'd rather not have it wait. That's why I want it to just skip to the next one if it takes more than 2 seconds.

Comment: Just a thought but could you try adding all the iframes to the page that you need and then change their location using the locations in the array? By that I mean start them out with a src="about:blank"

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. Do you know exactly what's happening when it get "stuck"? Because if "stuck" means hitting a loop or some other error then setTimeout won't help you. In my experience, code set to execute with setTimeout will happen when the given delay has passed or when other code has stopped executing, whichever happens LAST. In other words, I don't think you can interrupt currently running code with a setTimeout, which seems to be what you're asking.

I know that's sort of a non-answer; I suggest nailing down the nature of the stuckness instead.

Comment: Yea, settimeout might not be what I am looking for.  Just some way to stop the current function and move to the next one. And for what makes it stuck, during the commented section it is loading external pages. Usually (95% of the time) it loads in fractions of a second and works perfectly, but sometimes it finds a page that is slow/large file/missing/whatever and may take longer to load.  For those pages I want it to just skip and move on.

Comment: Thoughtful handling of the XMLHttpRequest object may be helpful. Frameworks (e.g. jQuery) abstract this, usually only giving you the ability to make callbacks execute when the ajax call has returned. If you monitor the XMLHttpRequest object directly, you *might* be able to finesse this kind of thing. Never tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

You could "try" to use iframe.contentDocument.readyState, but I say "try" with little confidence because with my tests it always came out to the "complete" state, but possibly when you run in to some pages that take awhile to load they may stay in some of the previous states.

For more information on this and the different states view this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx